# PHP read multiline csv file to variables

Tags: php, csv

I'd like to use weather forecast data on my website. There are numerical weather forecast output in a CSV file. I can read CSV file from link, then I can choose one forecasted variable, but I can't save each "forecasted number" to PHP variable. Could you help me please?

```
<?php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$nextday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 3 days'));

$lat = "40";
$lon = "19.5";
$file = fopen('http://oos.soest.hawaii.edu/erddap/griddap/NCEP_Global_Best.csv?tmp2m[('.$today.'T00:00:00Z):1:('.$nextday.'T00:00:00Z)][('.$lat.'):1:('.$lat.')][('.$lon.'):1:('.$lon.')],ugrd10m[('.$today.'T00:00:00Z):1:('.$nextday.'T00:00:00Z)][('.$lat.'):1:('.$lat.')][('.$lon.'):1:('.$lon.')],vgrd10m[('.$today.'T00:00:00Z):1:('.$nextday.'T00:00:00Z)][('.$lat.'):1:('.$lat.')][('.$lon.'):1:('.$lon.')],pratesfc[('.$today.'T00:00:00Z):1:('.$nextday.'T00:00:00Z)][('.$lat.'):1:('.$lat.')][('.$lon.'):1:('.$lon.')],rh2m[('.$today.'T00:00:00Z):1:('.$nextday.'T00:00:00Z)][('.$lat.'):1:('.$lat.')][('.$lon.'):1:('.$lon.')]', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  $T = $line[3];
  $temp1 = ????????;
  $temp2 = ????????;
  $temp3 = ????????;
      ...
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Now if I try `$temp1 = $T[0]`

I get

> tK2222222222222322222222222

Comment: What variable do you want to output?

Comment: First, I'd recommend using `curl` instead of `fopen` for URLs. It's safer and much easier to troubleshoot. Second, the first line line of the CSV is the headers, while the second line is informational. You can use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to map the subsequent rows to sane keys, which you can then decide what you want to do with it.

Comment: I would like to output all the predicted weather variables like temperature, precipitation, wind (u,v)... to php $temp1, $temp2, $precipitation1, $precipitation2...

Comment: Not sure how we can give a complete answer without actually seeing the data, but `$line` is going to be an array, `$line[3]` is going to be a string, meaning `$T` is a string.  If you do `$T[0]`, that means you are getting the first character of that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a block of code I use to parse out CSV files.

```
  $csvFile = fopen('portfolio.csv', 'r');
  $data = array();
  while ($row = fgetcsv($csvFile)) 
  {
      $data[] = $row;
  }
  fclose($csvFile);
  var_dump($data);
```

At the end of this loop, the entire CSV file is loaded into `$data`.

Loop through the `$data` array to do what you need.

```
$data[0][0] will contain A1
$data[0][1] will contain B1 and so on...

$data[1][0] will contain A2
$data[1][1] will contain B2 and so on...
```